# ARCore android scenform :Cannot use the same ViewRenderable with multiple SceneViews

Tags: android, arcore

My application does image detection using arcore augmentedimages and shows a viewrenderable once the image detected. If i close the app after the image has been detected and viewrenderable is shown, then reopen the application, the app crashes once the image is detected, throwing

> IllegalStateException: Cannot use the same ViewRenderable with
>   multiple SceneViews

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot, PID: 4313
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use the same ViewRenderable with multiple SceneViews.
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.RenderViewToExternalTexture.attachView(RenderViewToExternalTexture.java:131)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ViewRenderable.attachToRenderer(ViewRenderable.java:303)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.RenderableInstance.attachToRenderer(RenderableInstance.java:81)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.Node.activate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.Node.updateActiveStatusRecursively(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.Node.setEnabled(Unknown Source)
        at com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot.augmentedImage.HighlightNode.setVisible(HighlightNode.java:65)
        at com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot.augmentedImage.ModelNode.setChildVisible(ModelNode.java:69)
        at com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot.augmentedImage.ARTroubleshootActivity.yesPressed(ARTroubleshootActivity.java:178)
        at com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot.augmentedImage.ARTroubleshootActivity.lambda$TWxn4Gt1IyJ444bAiIcNiVnU0ng(ARTroubleshootActivity.java)
        at com.techaffinity.arroutertroubleshoot.augmentedImage.-$$Lambda$ARTroubleshootActivity$TWxn4Gt1IyJ444bAiIcNiVnU0ng.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

crash occurs at onUpdateFrame method at

```
node.setRenderable(viewRenderableCF);
arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(node);
```

> where 'viewRenderableCF' is CompletableFuture of type ViewRenderable

I am currently overcoming this problem by calling `System.exit(0)` in ondestroy() method.

Is there any better way to do this(clearing app from memory like swiping away the app preview in recent apps list)?

or

Is there any code related to arcore to clear out the instance of SceneView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the CompletableFuture null in the `onDestroy()` callback of the activity solves the problem. Even after the finish method is called the CompletableFuture of type `ViewRenderable` is still in the memory. When I go to the same activity again, the `ViewRenderable` is created from the old CompletableFuture. This is also the case for CompletableFuture of type `ModelRenderable` but for reasons I don't know, setting modelrenderable to the node doesn't cause this crash.

Answer (score 0):

try call this onDestroy/OnPause

`arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().onRemoveChild(node);`

Comment: @PanneerdasP can you debug and show what is set before the error? and maybe give some more code or the total error message.